# Ubuntu Shutdown during boot

Tags: shutdown

i have installed ubuntu 22.04 along side window 10, after upgrading Ubuntu my machine is shutdown immediately showing error pamouse serio3: synaptics :unable to initialize device
every-time its show error during boot and shutdown
please guide me what can i do to resolve the issue